# ElasticSearch Window Scroll Size

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I increase the scroll size of my ES scroll search query? The default appears to be 50 hits, but I would like to increase that to 100 or so. I cannot find a reference to adjusting the scroll window size in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your initial `scan` search request, simply specify the `size` parameter with how many documents you'd like each scroll request to return, e.g. 100:

```
POST /your_index/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=1m 
{
    "query": { "match_all": {}},
    "size":  100
}
```

or more simply

```
GET /your_index/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=1m&size=100
```

Also note that you will get more than 100 documents back, because the `size` is per-shard, so if you really want only 100 docs per batch and your have (e.g.) 5 shards per index, simply use `size: 20`, it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /your_index/_search?search_type=scan
{    
    "scroll:" "1M"
    "query": { "match_all": {}},
    "size":  100    
}
```

This should also work. Putting the scroll into the braces. Will be neater for reading later.